# Strange behaviour with Material-UI Text Field and Redux state trying to set default value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am trying to set a defaultValue property for a Text Field by getting the value from my Redux state however it is not updating accordingly.

I have passed the value as a prop from the container component down to my edit component like so:

```
render() {

const {data} = this.props

     return (
          <editcomponent value={this.props.data.value}
     )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

  return {
    data: state.dataReducer
  }

}
```

In my edit component I tried to just display it first and this works fine:

```
render() {

     return (
          <h3>this.props.value</h3>
     )
}
```

When I reload the page with new data in my Redux state it updates accordingly. However, when I try the exact same thing except with a Text Field in which I am setting defaultValue it does not update.

This doesn't work:

```
render() {

     return (
          <TextField id="textfield_id" defaultValue={this.props.value}/>
     )
}
```

It will work the initial time, and then when I reload the page with new data it doesn't set the defaultValue to the new data it stays the same as it originally was. If I use value instead then it will change the data but it won't allow me to edit the text box value anymore.

How can I solve this? I want to be able to have a defaultValue set by my Redux state and allow the value to be changed as the user changes/deletes what's in the text box.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem and I fixed by following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36959225/842097

Don't use `defaultValue`, but set `initialValues` in the state

`initialValues: {
  name: theName
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this bug as well,  solved by mapping the props to a state first and then using that state instead with value prop.

```
function updateValue(e) {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
}

render {
  return (
    <TextField id="textfield_id" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.updateValue}/>
  );
}
```