# className in <Field> in Redux Form

Tags: redux, redux-form, classname

I've created a redux-form and i want to add className to each Field to customize them with css.
The code for each field is:

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(requestAccountsFilter)}>
        <FormGroup row>
          <Field
            id="symbol"
            name="symbol"
            type="text"
            component={inputField}
            placeholder="Enter Product Here"
          />
          <Field id="side" name="side" component={inputField} type="select">
            <option value={null}>Any</option>
            <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
            <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
          </Field>
          <Field id="status" name="status" component={inputField} type="select">
            <option value={null}>Any</option>
            <option value="Working">Working</option>
            <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
          </Field>
          <Button name="submit-btn" className="filter-submit-btn" color="danger" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </FormGroup>
  </Form>
```

I've added a className tag but i see that neither the placeholder i've added is shown nor the className. How can i customize each field?

Comment: It all depends on what your `inputField` function looks like. Can you show it to us?

Comment: All props that you passed to `Field` will be available in your `inputField` component. So in your `inputField` component, you just need to destructure props like `<inputField {...this.props} />`. In this way all the props that you pass to `Field` will be available in your `inputField` component.`

Comment: My inputField component is like this:export default field => (
  <div>
    <Input {...field.input} type={field.type}>
      {field.children}
    </Input>
    {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error &&
    <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>}
  </div>
);

Comment: Rather than pasting your code in the comment. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<Field 
    type="text" 
    className="myClass"
    component={InputField} 
    placeholder="Type here..."
/>
```

and your custom `InputField` should be something like

(I've taken this example from http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/submitValidation/)

```
export const InputField = ({ input, type, placeholder, className, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={placeholder} type={type} className={className}/>
      {meta.touched && meta.error && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
  </div>
)
```

or a better approach, if too many props are there, You can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
export const InputField = (field) => ( 
    <div> 
        <input {...field.input} {...field} /> 
        {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error && <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>} 
    </div>
)
```

`{...field}` will extract all props that you have passed in `Field`.

You can take a look at this official redux-form example: http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/react-widgets/ to get more idea.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The last InputField Component shows me an error that cannot read props meta and input

Comment: Did first one work? I'm not much sure about the second because I haven't tried it myself. I'll need to look into it.

Comment: Nor the first is working. It's working only if i assign a value directly. to be more specific if i assign etc value="fsfsdfs" it will work but if i assign value={value} and in my component i set value="fsdfsdfsd" it will not work

Comment: I've also made some other changes. Can you please try updated answer?

Comment: No, it didnt work. Also the return throws me an error

Comment: I've reverted my answer, I tested the first version and it's working fine. Can you please copy as it is an try now?

Comment: It's fine mate thanks a lot! But i want to ask you something else. i want my box to have a default value. Does a box have a value prop so as to assign a value in it?

Comment: So it worked? You might find reading this helpful. http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958251/unable-set-a-default-value-in-redux-form-w-react

Comment: Thanks a lot :) You were really helpful :)

Comment: Did it wok or not?

Comment: Glad it worked. If you are satisfied with the answer then you can mark the answer as accepted. It will also help others in the future for reference. :)

Answer (score 1):

> You can use object destructuring method to set className.

```html
<Field 
        type="text" 
        input={{className:'red'}}
        component={InputField} 
        placeholder="Type here..."
    />
```

Comment: I really like this approach over the others, and removes the need for adding className on a component, something that can be considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that you are using a custom renderer by saying `component={InputField}`, but for others coming here (since I can't find it in the docs): if you are using one of the built-in renderers like `component="input"` or `component="select"`, you can just add `className` and the renderer will apply it, e.g.:

```
<Field name="foo" component="select" className="form-control">
</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, whatever you pass to the Field component should be passed to the InputField component as *input* prop. So, your InputField Component should look something like this:

```
<div> 
    <InputField  {...field.input} > {field.children} </InputField> 
    {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error && <span className="error"> 
    {field.meta.error}</span>}
</div>
```